# ngRepeat inside cloned element

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that consists of a template with a repeater. Inside the linking function, I want to be able to clone a part of my template and have it maintain the binding to the repeater.

My template:

```
var template = '<div>{{title}}<ul><li ng-repeat="msg in msgs">{{msg.value}}</li></ul></div>';
```

I am using $compile like so:

```
$clone = $element.children().first().clone();
$element.append($compile($clone)($scope));
```

Here is a link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gaig/bk4C2/3/

As you can see, the second cloned list does not receive the model changes that the original list does. It is my intention that both of these lists are identically bound to the model.